# Airflow Custom Sensor: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_records'

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow v1.9.0 with Celery Executor. I have configured different workers with different queue names like DEV, QA, UAT, PROD. I have written a custom sensor which polls a source db connection and a target db connection and run different queries and do some checks before triggering downstream-tasks. This has been running fine for multiple workers. In one of the workers, this sensor is giving an AttributeError Issue:

```
$ airflow test PDI_Incr_20190407_v1  checkCCWatermarkDt 2019-04-09
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,769] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key [celery/celery_ssl_active] not found in config
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,770] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will run without SSL
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,771] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,817] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py:2160: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to ExternalTaskSensor. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'check_existence': True}
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,989] {base_hook.py:80} INFO - Using connection to: 172.16.20.11:1521/GWPROD
[2019-04-09 10:02:57,991] {base_hook.py:80} INFO - Using connection to: dmuat.cwmcwghvymd3.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/DMUAT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 528, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1584, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/sensors.py", line 78, in execute
    while not self.poke(context):
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/plugins/PDIPlugin.py", line 29, in poke
    wm_dt_src = hook_src.get_records(self.sql)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_records'
```

Although when I run the same test command from Scheduler CLI, it is running fine. The above issue looks like a database connection issue.

For debugging, I checked the DB Connections from Airflow UI:
Data Profiling -> Ad Hoc Query
Query: Select 1 from dual; -- This worked fine

I also did telnet from the worker node to the DB Host and port and that also went fine.

**Custom Sensor Code:**

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.operators.sensors import SqlSensor

class SensorWatermarkDt(SqlSensor):

    def __init__(self, conn_id, sql, conn_id_tgt, sql_tgt, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sql = sql
        self.conn_id = conn_id
        self.sql_tgt = sql_tgt
        self.conn_id_tgt = conn_id_tgt
        super(SqlSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def poke(self, context):
        hook_src = BaseHook.get_connection(self.conn_id).get_hook()
        hook_tgt = BaseHook.get_connection(self.conn_id_tgt).get_hook()

        self.log.info('Poking: %s', self.sql)
        self.log.info('Poking: %s', self.sql_tgt)
        wm_dt_src = hook_src.get_records(self.sql)
        wm_dt_tgt = hook_tgt.get_records(self.sql_tgt)

        if wm_dt_src <= wm_dt_tgt:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class PDIPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "PDIPlugin"
    operators = [SensorWatermarkDt]
```

Airflow DAG Snippet:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
from airflow.operators import SensorWatermarkDt
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'SenseTeam',
    #'depends_on_past': True,
    'depends_on_past' : False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 7, 17, 00),
    'email': [],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'queue': 'PENTAHO_UAT'
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='PDI_Incr_20190407_v1',
          default_args=default_args,
          max_active_runs=1,
          concurrency=1,
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=24),
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=23*60))

checkCCWatermarkDt = \
        SensorWatermarkDt(task_id='checkCCWatermarkDt',
                          conn_id='CCUSER_SOURCE_GWPROD_RPT',
                          sql="SELECT MAX(CC_WM.CREATETIME) as CURRENT_WATERMARK_DATE FROM CCUSER.CCX_CAPTUREREASON_ETL CC_WM INNER JOIN CCUSER.CCTL_CAPTUREREASON_ETL CC_WMLKP ON  CC_WM.CAPTUREREASON_ETL = CC_WMLKP.ID AND UPPER(CC_WMLKP.DESCRIPTION)= 'WATERMARK'",
                          conn_id_tgt = 'RDS_DMUAT_DMCONFIG',
                          sql_tgt = "SELECT MAX(CURRENT_WATERMARK_DATE) FROM DMCONFIG.PRESTG_DM_WMD_WATERMARKDATE WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'CCUSER'",
                          poke_interval=60,
                          dag=dag)
...
```

I have restarted web server, scheduler and airflow worker after adding this plugin in this worker node.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please give us how do you call your `PDIPlugin`

Comment: Added in Airflow DAG Snippet. However, I noticed that cx_Oracle was not installed in this box. After installing and configuring cx_Oracle, it worked. Although not sure, if it is the correct way.
If the issue occurred because of a missing cx_Oracle module, I would expect the error message to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I have met this problem as well when I tried to use airflow's hook to connect to Teradata database, so I have read the code in airflow, we can see the get_hook() function in the path: /<your python path(may like: /usr/lib64/python2.7/)>/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py:

```
    def get_hook(self):
    try:
        if self.conn_type == 'mysql':
            from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
            return MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'google_cloud_platform':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
            return BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'postgres':
            from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
            return PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'hive_cli':
            from airflow.hooks.hive_hooks import HiveCliHook
            return HiveCliHook(hive_cli_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'presto':
            from airflow.hooks.presto_hook import PrestoHook
            return PrestoHook(presto_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'hiveserver2':
            from airflow.hooks.hive_hooks import HiveServer2Hook
            return HiveServer2Hook(hiveserver2_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'sqlite':
            from airflow.hooks.sqlite_hook import SqliteHook
            return SqliteHook(sqlite_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'jdbc':
            from airflow.hooks.jdbc_hook import JdbcHook
            return JdbcHook(jdbc_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'mssql':
            from airflow.hooks.mssql_hook import MsSqlHook
            return MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'oracle':
            from airflow.hooks.oracle_hook import OracleHook
            return OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'vertica':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.vertica_hook import VerticaHook
            return VerticaHook(vertica_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'cloudant':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.cloudant_hook import CloudantHook
            return CloudantHook(cloudant_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'jira':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.jira_hook import JiraHook
            return JiraHook(jira_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'redis':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.redis_hook import RedisHook
            return RedisHook(redis_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'wasb':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.wasb_hook import WasbHook
            return WasbHook(wasb_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'docker':
            from airflow.hooks.docker_hook import DockerHook
            return DockerHook(docker_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'azure_data_lake':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.azure_data_lake_hook import AzureDataLakeHook
            return AzureDataLakeHook(azure_data_lake_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'azure_cosmos':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.azure_cosmos_hook import AzureCosmosDBHook
            return AzureCosmosDBHook(azure_cosmos_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'cassandra':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.cassandra_hook import CassandraHook
            return CassandraHook(cassandra_conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'mongo':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.mongo_hook import MongoHook
            return MongoHook(conn_id=self.conn_id)
        elif self.conn_type == 'gcpcloudsql':
            from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_sql_hook import CloudSqlDatabaseHook
            return CloudSqlDatabaseHook(gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=self.conn_id)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

It means if you don't have this kind of type connection then the get_hook will return a 'NoneType' Type. So that is the reason why it happened.

How to Resolve:
Add a your own hook is best way in airflow , I had a sample for Teradata here:

```
# cat teradata_hook.py

from builtins import str

import jaydebeapi

from airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook import DbApiHook


class TeradataJdbcHook(DbApiHook):
   
    conn_name_attr = 'teradata_conn_id'
    default_conn_name = 'teradata_default'
    supports_autocommit = True

    def get_conn(self):
        conn = self.get_connection(getattr(self, self.conn_name_attr))
        host = conn.host
        url = 'jdbc:teradata://' + host + '/TMODE=TERA'
        login = conn.login
        psw = conn.password
        jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar,/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-without-hadoop/jars/tdgssconfig-16.20.00.06.jar'
        jdbc_driver_name = "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"

        conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=jdbc_driver_name,
                                  url=url,
                                  driver_args=[str(login), str(psw)],
                                  jars=jdbc_driver_loc.split(","))
        return conn

    def set_autocommit(self, conn, autocommit):
        """
        Enable or disable autocommit for the given connection.

        :param conn: The connection
        :return:
        """
        conn.jconn.setAutoCommit(autocommit)
```

Then you can call this hook to connect teradata database (or other database which has jdbc driver ):

```
[root@myhost transfer]# cat h.py 
import util

from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from teradata_hook import TeradataJdbcHook


sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  TERADATA_TABLE where month_key='202009'"

conn_id='teradata_account@dbname' # this is my environment's id format

hook = TeradataJdbcHook(conn_id)
records = hook.get_records(sql)
print(records)
if str(records[0][0]) in ('0', '',):
    print("No Records")
else:
    print("Has Records")
```

It return's result: [(7734133,)]